# DictReader change keys to upper

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I'm trying to resolve import issues in dictreader when fields aren't formatted as expected, forcing all fieldnames to uppercase (or lowercase) would resolve that.

Here's the basic code I'm using, though I can't seem to update the rows in dict.

```
f = open(sourceFile,'rb')
reader = csv.DictReader(f, dialect='excel')
for r in reader:
    r.update(dict((k.upper(), v) for k, v in r.iteritems()))
```

The desired output is the same list of dictionaries but will all keys set to uppercase.

I'm missing the 'update', I'm fine writing to a new list. Just getting a little frustrated.

Comment: Your code will duplicate keys, those that were not yet uppercase to begin with. Otherwise it works just fine, but you don't seem to be *using* each row. You may as well just use `r = dict((k.upper(), v) for k, v in r.iteritems())` then use `r` *in that loop* to do what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a new list:

```
new = [{k.upper(): v for k, v in r.iteritems()} for r in reader]
```

Or if you want to make one dict at a time:

```
for r in reader:
    r = {{k.upper(): v for k, v in r.iteritems()}
    # use r
```

Answer (score 7):

To avoid iterating through your entire file, modify the `fieldnames` attribute on the DictReader, as in:

```
f = open(sourceFile,'rb')
reader = csv.DictReader(f, dialect='excel')
reader.fieldnames = [name.upper() for name in reader.fieldnames]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a generator to return an uppercased keys dictionary for each row:

```
def uppercased(reader):
    for r in reader:
        yield {k.upper(): v for k, v in r.iteritems()}
```

then use this as:

```
with open(sourceFile,'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, dialect='excel')
    for r in uppercased(reader):
        # use `r` like you normally would
```

Comment: Thanks Martijn, yield is a new function to me, thanks for thsi.